# Ajax Synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax

O que devo fazer nesta situação. Tenho um script onde tenho que desabilitar na função AJAX a opção: `async : false` .  Faço isso pois retorna uma variável de forma errada, anterior a última que foi solicitada.

Se eu coloco false, retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Como procedo neste tipo de situação:

```
var o = 0;
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                dataType : "json",
                async : false,
                success : function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(i,v){
                        if(g == v.k){
                            o = v.u;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

alert(o)
```

Se eu não coloco como true, ele retorna 0. Já se eu coloco como false ele retorna a mensagem acima. O que fazer nessa situação?

Comment: Requisições assíncronas estão depreciadas nos navegadores modernos, por isso você recebe esta mensagem. Procure se informar sobre callbacks e promisses para resolver o seu problema quanto a variável de forma assíncrona.

Comment: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Comment: Pequena correção: o @Oeslei quis dizer "requisições síncronas" estão depreciadas...

Comment: São vária chamadas ajax e elas devem seguir uma ordem para executar?

Comment: @Onaiggac Faz tempo essa pergunta, mas acredito que na época ela estava dentro de uma requisão, e o retorno deveria ser conforme a busca, não recordo se era o ajax ou o each que não estavam procedendo com a ordem (acredito que seja o ajax, pois o each não faz isso). Se não me engano, utilizei `.done()`.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que fazer um *Callback*. O código não espera o Ajax terminar, é **assíncrono**.

Seria assim:

```
var o = 0;

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType : "json",
    async : false,
    success : function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i,v){
            if(g == v.k){
                o = v.u;
                recebeValor(o);
            }
        });
    }
});

function recebeValor(result){
    alert(result);
}
```